# Select a row from the group of row on a particular column value

Tags: sql, select

I want to write a query to achieve the following. I have a table `xyz` in which there are multiple row with same column value(1) in say column a.

I want to find in column b doesn't have a particular value for the set of rows with value 1 in column a.

```
Table xyz
---------

a  b   
1  te

1  we

1  re

2  te

2  re

3  ge

4  re
```

So basically I want to find if the column b does not have the value 'te' for a set of values from column a

when i do

```
Select a from xyz where b <> 'te'
group by a
```

I will get `1,2,3 and 4` both for the result.

But I want the result should only contain 1 and 2. Please help.

Comment: what is the criteria for you to chose `1` and `2`

Comment: Class Sub                                                           1     eng                     1 Phy 1 chem 2 eng 2 chem 2 phy 3 eng 3 his 3 geo I want to find class where sub geo doesnt exists.

Comment: If that is the requirement then your query will return correct answer.

Comment: Then using your original example, where you want to find the values of `a` for which 'te' doesn't exist, you want to return `3 and 4` instead of `1, 2, 3 and 4` right?  The fact that you said you wanted to return `1 and 2` is what is confusing as that's just a simple search for where `te` DOES exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a from xyz where (b<>'te') and ((a=1) or (a=2))
```

or as variant

```
select a from xyz where (b<>'te') and (a in (1, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I didn't and still don't understand what you are asking. Could you try and restate it? The only non-trivial interpretation I can come up with that would return 1 and 2 based on this data would be:

> What are the values of `a` such that there is a row with both `a` and
>   'te' and a row with both `a` and a value other than 'te'

in which case a query would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT q1.a FROM (SELECT a FROM xyz WHERE b='te') q1
JOIN (SELECT a FROM xyz WHERE b!='te') q2 ON
q1.a=q2.a
```

The interpretation which corresponds with returning `3 and 4` in your example or with returning `1 and 2` in your `geo` example would be:

> What are the values of `a` for which a `te` row does not exist?

in which case a query would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a FROM xyz WHERE a NOT IN (SELECT a FROM xyx WHERE b='te')
```

as shown [here](http://ideone.com/ekSf8I) (sqlfiddle is acting up, so I used ideone)

Comment: Class  Sub


1 eng


1 Phy


1 chem


2 eng


2 chem


2 phy


3 eng


3 his


3 geo


I want to find class where sub geo doesnt exists. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a from xyz
where b! = 'tz' and 
a in (select a from xyz where b = 'tz')
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for you:

```
Select a from xyz where b = 'te'
group by a
```